# i was getting blank response from ajax can any one tell me where i did mistake

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my code I want my second option list to pull data from database when the first list was selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#category').change(function(){
   var id=$(this).val();


   $.ajax({
       type:'post',
       url:'get_select.php',
       data:{'id':id},
       cache:false,
       success:function (html) {
           $("#type").html(html);
       }
   });
});
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="">
<label>Category :</label><br>
<select id="category" name="category" class="form-control">
    <?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "mysql";
    $database = "crm";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);


    $sql1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT list_name from links_list ");
    $sql1->execute();

    while ($data1 = $sql1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data1['list_name']; ?>"><?php echo $data1['list_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
    }

    ?>
</select><br><br>
<label>Types :</label><br>
<select id="type" name="type" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">-select-</option>
</select><br><br>
</form>
```

get_select.php

```
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "mysql";
    $database = "crm";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

    $cn = $_POST['id'];
    $sql1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT id from links_list where 
    list_name='$cn'");
    $sql1->execute();

    while ($data1 = $sql1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $link = $data1['id'];
        echo'<option value="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</option>';
       }
```

I want to get second list item when first was selected, depending on first, the second list should, in my code ajax response coming blanlk

Comment: this doesn't look right, does it? : `var dataString = 'id'+id;`

Comment: `data:dataString,` to `data:{'id':id},`

Comment: ya i did but no use, same result it showing blank

Comment: Put an console.log on datastring and print the results. Then, you can see, what the problem is.

Comment: @DeekshithShetty chane your question with updation you have done with `data:`

Comment: Can you just call get_select.php directly from the browser. with id as a get_parameter and see if it is giving results or not? That will make it clear

Comment: in console it showing blank @UmashankarDas

Comment: ya i did calling directly get_select.php then it showing result @UmashankarDas

Comment: is your ajax function getting called or not? Modify the console.log to an alert and see if a pop-up comes or not?

Comment: @DeekshithShetty have you checked my answer?

Comment: it is called when i right click it and open in new tab it showing blank @UmashankarDas

Comment: ya i did update @B.Desai

Comment: so have you change get_select.php? as in my answer @DeekshithShetty

Comment: ya i did @B.Desai

Comment: check my answer @DeekshithShetty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be not a solution .but it will correct your some mistakes

**1 :** Option should be append like this `$("#type").append(html);`

**2 :** And also add ajax error handler .

```
$.ajax({
       type:'post',
       url:'get_select.php',
       data:{id:id},
       cache:false,
       success:function (html) {
           $("#type").empty();
           $("#type").append(html);
       },
       error:function(request,string_error,error){
           alert(string_error);
       }

   });
```

**3 :**  Instead of echoing inside the while loop  . concatenate and echo after while loop like this

```
  $concat ="";
  while ($data1 = $sql1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $link = $data1['id'];
      $concat.= '<option value="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</option>';
  }
   echo $concat;
```

Comment: ya i did no use

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @DeekshithShetty

Comment: ya, it's working only if I hardcore field name in get_select.php, it 'll receive from there, but id is posting blank, now also can u help me with it

Comment: get_select.php   echo file_get_contents('php://input');    alert in ajax success alert(html); know value posting or not  @DeekshithShetty

Comment: sorry i didn't get u, where should i echo and what?

Comment: echo file_get_contents('php://input'); echo this in get_select.php  and comment all other lines of code except this line . and in ajax success function  inside alert like this alert(html); @DeekshithShetty

Comment: ya its showing id=manu , manu is my field name, it means data post working currectly rit??

Comment: ya posting, and I found the problem, actually, it was my IDE problem, I am using PHP storm, it was using its own server in that server post always sending blank, thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

from your updated code I think you have issue in **get_select.php**. In query you are selecting `links` and in while loop you are using `id` so you need change here:

```
$host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "mysql";
    $database = "crm";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

    $cn = $_POST['id'];
    $sql1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT id from links_list where 
    list_name='$cn'"); //<-----------select id or you can change field name
    $sql1->execute();

    while ($data1 = $sql1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $link = $data1['id']; //<-----------use id or use whatever you are selecting
        echo'<option value="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</option>';
       }
```

Comment: Have you check console? what you are getting there?

Comment: there change function was working and it comming back with blank data

Comment: check this query : `"SELECT id from links_list where list_name='$cn'"` echo this query and copy paste directly in  phpmyadmin (or on mysql) and see it returns result or not

Comment: in my database, one list name is there is 'manu' if I wrote that name instead of $cn it was showing result but not in when received from post method

Comment: where i have to echo $cn if did this in get_select.php is it come it option list? i did that but it was  showing blank

Comment: yes write it in  get_select.php. and in your ajax success method write `console.log(data);` and see the console what it return

Comment: previously when the select option in the first section,  get_select.php showing in console network tab, but when I wrote console.log(data) it is not functioning

Comment: where have you write console.log ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake write `console.log(html)`

Comment: success:function (html) {
           $("#type").html(html); insted of function (html) {
           $("#type").html(html) i wrote console.log

Comment: change `data` with `html`

Comment: ya did same as last time

Comment: is there any option to see my ajax is posting any data or not?

Comment: thanks for u r time, i got solution and i clicked right mark to it

Comment: sorry his solution was working only when I hardcore field name, if data posted from Ajax it showing blank

Comment: how ? in my first select option value is showing manu ect. , but how to that option value is posting or not

Answer (score 0):

In javascript

```
data:dataString,
```

to

```
data:{'id':id},
```

And in php

```
 $link = $data1['id'];
```

to

```
$link = $data1['links'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a 3 stage diagnosis.

1. Verify if your data is getting populated properly or not in the 1st set of options.
2. Next, verify if, the onchange method is getting called or not.
3. After that check if get_select.php is showing correct results.

Verify every stage and check if results are working. It is difficult for us to verify this since, we dont know the results of the 1st set of PHP calls. Also, if your db call in get_select.php does not match what you're sending, you will still get empty data.

Check every stage and see if results are coming as expected.

This answer will help you diagnose future problems like this.

Comment: how to check that data is getting populated properly or not

Comment: is it possible to check the is my file sending data to get_select.php. or not?

Comment: if your code is functional, you will see the options on the webpage for the 1st set of database calls. Are you able to see that? Check for option 1.

2nd check, put an alert inside the ("#category").change . if that alert changes, you can see the call. 

3rd check. if the above works, verify the datastring. if that is empty, your ajax call will fail. 

or, simply, run the command on a debugger. of the browser and see what is happening.

If you have a public link somewhere, share, it , we can see, what is happening